# Подключение бота только к одному каналу Discord

Tags: node.js, discord-api

Есть 3 голосовых канала `общий`, `общий2`, `флудилка`. Как сделать так, чтобы бот отслеживал третий канал на наличие пользователей? И если есть пользователь - заходил туда и выполнял некоторую функцию. Используемый модуль - `disord.js`.

```
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
  let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel
  let channel = bot.channels.get("id channel")

  if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {

    channel.join()
    .then(connection => {;
      const dispatcher = connection.play('mp3 file');
      dispatcher.on("end", end => {
          // ...  
      });
  });

  } else if(newUserChannel === undefined){
      // ...
  }
})
```

Это отслеживает всех пользователей и при каждом подключении в любой канал бот заходит в 3. Как сделать чтобы он заходил только когда в 3 зашли?

Comment: И что у вас не получилось? Читали апи ? Почитайте еще [An Idiot's Guide](https://anidiots.guide/) может поможет. А так скидывайте то что попробовали сделать и что у вас не получилось, будем разбираться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (old_member, new_member) => {
    // channel_name - название канала, к которому должен присоединяться бот в случае,
    // если в этом канале появился пользователь.
    let channel = client.channels.find(val => val.name == 'channel_name');
    // check будет содержать в себе null, если new_member подключился не к нужному каналу.
    let check = channel.members.find(val => val.user.username == new_member.user.username);
    if (check != null) {
        // Здесь выполняется то, что вам нужно в случае, если в нужном канале появился пользователь
        console.log(`Will connect to ${channel.name}`);
    } else {
        // Здесь код, который выполняется в случае, если пользователь зашёл не в нужный канал. Этот блок else можно вообще удалить.
        console.log(`Will not connect to ${channel.name}`);
    }
});
```

Вот так будет выглядеть вывод в консоль при перемещении пользователя по каналам на сервере:

[image: Вывод в консоль]

Вам осталось только заполнить блоки if и else тем, что вам нужно.